# OpenCart category product view modification

Tags: opencart

How could I change the category product list view in Opencart to 6 product box slider?

By pushing the next button I could go to next six items and so on.

Comment: The carousel module does something like this for the banners. Have a look at that to begin with. It would be a fair amount of work though.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for the thing you need is *[Combining Carousel and Latest Module](http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/combining-carousel-and-latest-module/)*. I don't know if you look for a paid solution or not, but it seems a module like one of these will do the trick:

- *[Ocart Product Carousel](http://opencartart.com/ocart-product-carousel)*
- *[3D Carousel Selector List](http://opencartmarket.com/featured-categories-wall-3d-carousel-selector-list.html)*

(PS: I'm not the author of any module or related to them.)